# Bridging between network interfaces in linux

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, tunnel, bridge

Assume I have a linux computer, running an OpenVPN Access Server with the following interfaces:

wwan0 - Internet access, IP 212.179.50.50

tun0 - OpenVPN interface, IP 172.225.25.1 (the SERVER's VPN IP)

eth0 - Ethernet interface, connected to a switch and gets IP 10.0.0.10 (Switch's IP is 10.0.0.1)

What I am trying to do:

1. Allowing clients to connect to the OpenVPN server using the server's public internet IP (done that).
2. Allowing those clients who connect to the OpenVPN server, to PING the switch (10.0.0.1), and any other device connected to that switch.

What is the easy way of doing this (using ifconfig/iptables/etc).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your current iptables setup (from `iptables-save`)?

Comment: And perhaps you can share how the openvpn client(s) get set up; especially whether they learn to route the 10.0.0.0/24 traffic to the openvpn service or not.

Comment: If you have different networks, you really don't want to bridge between them, you need to route between them if you want to be able to ping between the networks. Bridges connect the same network, routers route between networks.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** use `ifconfig/iptables...` to achieve this, because you need clients be informed that the new subnet (10.0.0.0/24) is available thru the OpenVPN: hence, you are trying to modify the routing table **of the clients**, not of the server.

Luckily for us, though, `OpenVPN` will do that for you. Just add the following line

```
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

in your server configuration file, and you are done. What this does is to `push` to clients a route for the subnet in question (10.0.0.0/24 above) thru the tunnel. This will work whether you have rerouted all of the clients traffic thru the VPN or not, it does not matter. For this to work, just make sure that you have IPv4 allowed (but I bet you do, since you state that the OpenVPN already works) and that you have no `iptables` FORWARD rules blocking access to 10.0.0.0/24 and/or 172.225.25.0/24.

**P.S.:** why are you using public, routable addresses for your OpenVPN? You should use a private, non-routable subnet, drawn if you like in the range 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255. The address you are using, 172.225.25.1, is public and routable, and has been assigned already, to none other than Akamai Technologies, see [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/172.225.25.1).